# How to return both string and value within HttpResponse?

Tags: python, django

I need the code to return a string and value in HttpResponse but it returns only first value(val). Why should I do to return both val and val2? String I will use as message and I need val in function return to use it as value in next function,something like this:

```
def func1(request):
   data = json.loads(request.body)
   val = "string"
   val2 = data['email']
   return HttpResponse(val, val2)

def func2():
   val3 = func1
   val4 = "client %s" % val2
   if val4:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Comment: In what format does your client expect the data? Raw HTTP data is not structured, it's only a stream of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your client (web browser) expects one string as response:

```
return HttpResponse("a string: {}".format(val))
```

or use JSON for the response:

```
return JsonResponse({'message': 'a string', 'val': val})
```

or, to send a variable to the next Django view:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.session.get('val', None):
        # do something with the 'val' variable.
    else:
        request.session['val'] = 'somevalue'
        return HttpResponse('some message')
```

[More about Django session here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: String here just text that have no relation to val. In other words: which arguments should I place to function to return any string and any value with HttpResponse

Comment: If your client is a web browser, it will only accept *one* string. So you have to send `val` as a part of that string. Please clarify (edit your question) what exactly you are trying to do, so we can tell you how to better achieve that.

Comment: Okay, so is that function a client-side, Javascript function? Then you should go with a JSON response (see updated answer). Or are you trying to pass a value to Django on the next server request? Then it would be [session data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: second one, it is a django function. How to use session data here?

Comment: You shouldn't be returning an HttpResponse from func1, then.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JsonResponse` That will solved `CORS` problem also
        '''
            Handling content type for json no more to add content-type.
        '''

```
    def __init__(self, content={}, status=None,content_type='application/json'):
        super(JsonResponse, self).__init__(
            json.dumps(content),
            status=status, content_type=content_type)
```

and response will be like this :

`return JsonResponse({"message": " message", "subject": subject})`